# Javascript sync object with an array

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
var obj = {'a':true,'b':false,'c':false,'d':true}
```

and I have a synced array which contains keys whose values are `true` in the object.

```
var arr = ['a','d']
```

So if `obj` changes to following: (`a`'s value changed to `false`)

```
obj = {'a':false,'b':false,'c':false,'d':true}
```

Then `arr` should be synced to following: (`a` element gets removed from `arr`)

```
arr = ['d'];
```

I have thought of two solutions:

1. Whenever object changes, I manipulate the same arr by performing push/remove operation on that key in array depending on the value of the key in object. (Updates to the object can be easily detected using angularjs in my case)
2. Whenever object changes, I will replace old array with new array containing only those keys whose value is set to `true` in.

Which solution is better??

Comment: This is an interesting problem, but in practice do you really want to be doing something like this? Seems very error-prone.  Keep each fact in one place.  You can store the object only and then write a _function_ to return an array containing only the keys that have a value that is true.

Comment: Option 2 should be easier (and less error prone). Unless you have thousands of properties in your object, option 2 should be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that managing an external array is a practical solution. The array you are searching for represents a status of the object. So I suggest to add a method to the object that dynamically returns an array of properties based on their values:

```
var obj = {'a':true,'b':false,'c':false,'d':true};

obj.getPropertiesByState = function(state){
  var res = [];
  for (var key in this) {
    if (this[key] === state) {
      res.push(key);
    }
  }
  return res;
}

var trueProperties = obj.getPropertiesByState (true);
```

Comment: Typo error: var trueProperties = obj.getPropertiesByState(true);

Answer (score 2):

[**Live demo:**](http://jsfiddle.net/KG2y9/2/)

You could use a simple class:

```
function Pair(obj, arr) {
    this.obj_ = obj || {};
    this.arr_ = arr || [];
    this.updateArray();
};
Pair.prototype.set = function(key, val) {
    this.obj_[key] = val;
    this.updateArray();
};
Pair.prototype.updateArray = function() {
    this.arr_.length = 0;
    for (var key in this.obj_) {
        if (this.obj_.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (this.obj_[key] === true) {
                this.arr_.push(key);
            };
        };
    };
};
Pair.prototype.getArray = function() {
    return JSON.stringify(this.arr_);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on few things.

How many pairs you have in an object or how many such such objects you have.

Can you depict in brief your use case?

First one is less memory efficient as you are relying on `GC`. But its less error prone.

So if you have *less items*(say *50* or *100* may be) in an object than replacing the array(building the new array) should be better.

At times, *Less error-prone* code is ***better*** than *less memory efficient* code.

You mentioned you are using angular,  this might help you straight away if you are looking for code solution.

```
$scope.$watch('obj', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    $scope.selectedItems = $.map(newVal,function(k,v){
      if(k === true)
        return v;
    });
  },true);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's map function should be what you need.

```
var o = {'a':true,'b':false,'c':false,'d':true};

jQuery.map(o, function(val, idx){
  if(val)
   return idx;
});
```

if an Object changes, you could replace the old array with this: Still I don't think this is a pretty good solution..

Answer (score 0):

First one is better. In this case you need to remove only those whose values has been changed.

> e.g. We have 1000 thousands elements in an array. But only one is
>   changed. So it will only execute for one element.
>
> In your second case, it will check all the elements i.e time consuming
>   and processing.